# Allocating a pointer by passing it through two functions

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, double-pointer

What am I doing wrong here? Am I allocating memory to the original `charPtr` or something else? Why can I read the value of `charPtr` within `func2`but not in main (`charPtr` is `NULL` in main)?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void func2(char *charPtr)
{
        charPtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        *charPtr = 'c';
        printf("func2: %c\n", *charPtr);
}

void func1(char** charDoublePointer)
{
        //*charDoublePointer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        func2(*charDoublePointer);
}

int main(int argsc, char* argv[])
{
        char * charPtr = NULL;
        func1(&charPtr);

        printf("%c\n", *charPtr);
}
```

Comment: In `func2`, changes to what `charPtr` points to is not visible to calling functions.

Comment: Reading your title makes for headaches. Also, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one level of indirection. `func2` needs to take a `char**` just like `func1`. When you write:

```
void func2(char *charPtr)
{
        charPtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        *charPtr = 'c';
        printf("func2: %c\n", *charPtr);
}
```

You're just assigning the local variable `charPtr`, which has no effect on the outside program. Instead, write:

```
void func2(char **charPtr)
{
        *charPtr = malloc(sizeof(char)); //don't cast result of malloc
        **charPtr = 'c';
        printf("func2: %c\n", **charPtr);
}
```

Change the name to `charDoublePtr` if you insist.

And call it in `func1` like:

```
func2(charPtr);
```

Comment: Better yet: Use a return-value instead of an out-parameter.

Comment: Consider using `realloc` instead of `malloc` in the event `*charPtr` is not `NULL` you avoid the memory-leak.

Answer (score 1):

Function `func2` gets a copy of the original pointer. That is the parameter of functioon func2 is a local variable that will be destroyed after exiting the function.

```
void func2(char *charPtr);
```

You could define the functions the following way

```
char * func2()
{
        char * charPtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        *charPtr = 'c';
        printf("func2: %c\n", *charPtr);

        return charPtr;
}

void func1(char** charDoublePointer)
{
        //*charDoublePointer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        *charDoublePointer = func2();
}
```